# Give a detailed illustration of how the MVC works in Rails, and how the controller communicates with forms etc?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

Perhaps this can even become a Community Wiki, but I would love a detailed description of how the controller works - or rather, how I can get it to do what I want it to do.

I understand the general structure of MVC and how the model stores the db structure, and the controller interacts with the db and passes info to the view.

However, I am puzzled (on a fundamental level) about how to accomplish simple tasks using my controller. I know that if I want to create a new record for a model/object, I just do `object = Object.new(:name => "Object Name")` in the Rails console.

But how on earth would I do that in the CRUD elements of the controller and why?

Please use a simple example - e.g. showing a user the balance of their bank account (I know there are many complexities surrounding this, but ignore them for the sake of this explanation). What would the model look like (just include: Name, Address, Transaction Type (Deposits/Withdrawals), Balance).

What would a view look like? What would the controller look like? Any choices you make (like using a form) please explain them. Why would you use a form, as opposed to a drop down menu and (in layman terms) how does the form or drop down menu interact with the controller? How do I get the info captured there to the db and why am I doing it that way?

I know this sounds like a lot to ask, but I have done RailsTutorial.org, watched many Railscasts, read the Rails guides, and read many other tutorials and still have some basic gaps in my understanding of the way Rails works and why.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know how much more help I can be, but I understand your pain having just come to rails myself.  The article recommended by ghoppe, "Skinny Controller, Fat Model" explains the function of Ms Vs & Cs nicely.  Seeing as that does not fully answer your question I will try to explain the mechanics of each structure.

### Model

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  validates_presence_of :address

  def name              # Account does not have a name field, but User does so I will make a name method for Account and feed it name of the user it belongs to.
    user = self.user    # Account gets the user method with the <belongs_to :user> association
                        # note: Rails expects Accounts to have a user_id field so it can perform the "magic" to associate Accounts with Users 
    if user.name
      return user.name
    else
      return nil
    end
  end
end
```

The model describes your object.  Like an object in any OOP language you want to put all of your object logic here.  This includes the rails helpers for association(has_one, belongs_to, ...) and validation, as well as any other method or library you want the object to be able use throughout your Models Views and Controllers.

### Controller

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :name, :only => :edit, :destroy  # @account.name will be executed before the edit or destroy method(action) can be invoked on @account.  If the user who has the account has a name the action will execute.  

  def index                                      # This is a RESTful action and is mapped by Rails by default to an HTTP GET request.  Rails expects an index.html.erb or index.haml.erb or index.something in the Accounts view to map this action to.
    @accounts = Account.all                      # @accounts is an instance variable and will be accessible in the view this action is mapped to.
  end   

  def show
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])         # params[:id] is passed to the controller from the view. The params hash is the primary tool form moving data from a form or URL into a controller.  Anytime you click on the link_to the show or edit action of an object Rails will put that objects id in the params hash and call the appropriate action in that objects controller.  If you click the show link on an account it will call this action.  Now the instance variable in the view show.html.erb will hold a single account instead of an array     
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new                       # This initializes a new account with all the fields set to blank unless you specified a default in your migration.  This account has not been save to the db yet.  It is ready for a user to fill in.
    respond_to do |format|                       # Rails can automatically respond differently to different client request.  If a client i.e browser wants HTML rails responds with HTML.  If a client e.g. an API want XML Rails responds with XML.
      format.html # new.html.erb                 # 
      format.xml  { render :xml => @account }
    end
  end

  def edit
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])         # Same as show, but mapped to a different view
  end

  def create                                     # Finally we have a POST.  All the prior actions were GETs, but now we are saving some data to the db.
    @account = Account.new(params[:account])     # The :account key is special.  It is a hash of hashes. It is populated by the form fields in new.html.erb.  To access a specific field such as address we say <params[:account][:address]> and whatever the user entered in the address field in the View is at out fingers in the Controller. 

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.save                           # If the validations pass and the account gets saved redirect to the show page of the new record, otherwise refresh/render the new page (hopefully showing what error caused the record to fail to save).
        format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'Account was successfully created.') }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @account, :status => :created, :location => @account }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @account.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def update                                     # This is another of the seven RESTful Rails actions and results in a PUT request because you are updating an existing record 
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @account.update_attributes(params[:account])
        format.js                                # Rails can also respond with JavaScript.  Look up UJS. Rails 3 has made large improvements here. 
        format.html { redirect_to(@account, :notice => 'Account was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.js
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @account.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy                                    # This results in a DELETE 
    @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    @account.destroy                             # destroy is a more thourough delete and will check the options of this records associations and destroy the associated objects as well if they are dependant on this object.  The option <:dependant => :destroy> is not set for this object's only association: User.  The user this account belongs to will therefore survive the destruction of this account.

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(accounts_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end
end
```

### View

Hopefully you can draw your own logic from here.  The view is designed to render information passed as instance vars from a controller to a client: browser, api, smart phone.  As well as to pass information from a client to the controller via the params hash.  No complicated logic should get performed in a view even though a view with erb has the capability to execute any ruby code.

If an example view would also be helpful I am happy to oblige.

Comment: Wow DUDE. I must say....this has to be the most comprehensive, and well-thought through response I have ever gotten on any question I have asked. Thanks so much for taking the time man. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it helped.  I had the same question not three months ago.  Takes one to know one eh.

Comment: SO how did you conquer it so quickly? You coming from a Ruby background? Or a heavy programming background? I have been trying to slay this beast for a few months too...and even though I am making progress, it is tough, slow...step by step progress. Sometimes I feel like I hit a mountain and it is painful to get to the other side. How did you get over these problems, if you experienced any of them?

Comment: I wouldn't say I slayed it.  My background is film and animation, but I knew some java and some c.  I can't complain about ruby, I'm growing strangely attached to it.  Even javascript is growing on me.  I do run into a lot of unknowns, but my secret if I have one has gradually changed from google and SO to github.  Look at other peoples code and see how they did it.  I like these two repos for rails reference https://github.com/patcito/shapado https://github.com/diaspora/diaspora

Comment: Thanks for those links. Interesting...never thought about that switch. That's quite interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The best description of what the controller is:

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

The controller doesn't communicate with the Database. The controller talks to the model, which then communicate with the database.

When I was starting I found very useful to use scaffolding and just looking at what was created.

Do this:

```
rails generate scaffold Post name:string title:string content:text
```

Examine all files under the app/ folder. Examine the file config/routes

Then comment here your specific questions.

Comment: Nerian, thanks for those links. I have read them all...many times. I understand the function of routes and I understand what the controller does. I have also looked through the scaffold and it did give me some insight into the way it functions - e.g. it automatically generates 6 actions, and in each action it shows me how to do what that action does e.g. index: `@users = User.all`, etc. However, my main issue is how to get it to do what I want. Do you mind just using the bank transaction example to explain it ? Thanks.

Comment: As in...just to be clear: I understand why the scaffold generated what it did to do what the Rails Core team wants the scaffold to do. However, I don't understand (in intimate details) how to get the controller to do what I need it to do. If I want to show the customer their account balance, how would I do that and why would I do that? Would I use variables in the controller? What would I have in the view? Etc. I hope I am explaining it clearly.

Comment: @marcamillion: Sure. Take a look a the Index action. You will se that it makes a call Post.all – That query the database, through the Post model –  and store the result in a @variable. Every variable that you define as @ will be passed to the view. In the view you will have a mix of HTML and Ruby code. Ruby code is between <% %> and <%= > . The difference is that <%= %> will output the result. For example <%= Product.name %> output the name. <% Product.name %> will not. Take a look a the Index view. Ask me anything you don't understand.

Comment: I understand those things Nerian...it was more the nuanced stuff that smothers covered earlier that I needed clarity on. Thanks for trying though.

Answer (score 1):

At first, I thought this question was far too broad, along the lines of "how do I program?" But after reading your comments, I see what you're getting at. You don't quite grasp how MVC works in Rails and are wondering where your code goes.

What you should strive for is a Skinny Controller and a Fat Model. Keep logic out of views. So in your example, you calculate the account balance in the Model, and pass that information along (using the controller) to the view.

For a concise explanation for beginners with sample code, I recommend [this article over here](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2006/10/18/skinny-controller-fat-model).

Comment: Thanks for that article. You kinda have where I am going, I guess I am confused with what goes where and why. But more importantly, I am trying to figure out how the respective HTML elements interact with the Model & Controller. E.g. how does a form interact with the controller, and the model, etc.

For instance, in my example - calculating the account balance in the model makes sense. But then how do I get it from the model to the view? Specifically. In the model do I initialize an instance variable and then I call that variable from the view or do I call it from the controller.

Comment: Then once it is in the controller, how do I get to it from the view to display it? If someone could just do that simple example of the bank transaction for me...then that would help me BIG time. Because I can ask specific questions about why certain things were done. I am not being lazy, I am truly trying to learn how this stuff works. I am working on a web app, and feel stuck at a particular mountain. It is difficult for me to ask for help, because it has become complicated. My problems are gaps in the fundamental understand of how it works. So I am trying to abstract that and figure it out.

Comment: Once you calculate it in the model, you just display the method in the view. eg. <%= account.balance %> The account variable itself is populated depending on the action (eg. index) in the controller (eg. @accounts = Account.find_all) If you go through the example code in that link, it should become clear. Just replace people with accounts and age with account balance. :)